# Потоки в delphi

Tags: delphi

(Delphi 7, indy) Без потока программа работает в зависшем состоянии. Попытаюсь с потоком, компилируется . при нажатии на кнопку (access violation on address 0049974c)

```
unit Unit1;
interface
uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, IdCookieManager, IdIOHandler, IdIOHandlerSocket,
  IdIOHandlerStack, IdSSL, IdSSLOpenSSL, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent,
  IdTCPConnection, IdTCPClient, IdHTTP, ExtCtrls, Unit2;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    IdHTTP1: TIdHTTP;
    IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
    IdCookieManager1: TIdCookieManager;
    Button1: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Timer1: TTimer;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    my:myth;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation
{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  my:=myth.Create(true);
  my.Priority:=tpNormal;
  my.FreeOnTerminate:=True;
  my.Resume;
end;

end.
```

Поток

```
unit Unit2;
interface
uses
Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, IdCookieManager, IdIOHandler, IdIOHandlerSocket,
  IdIOHandlerStack, IdSSL, IdSSLOpenSSL, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent,
  IdTCPConnection, IdTCPClient, IdHTTP, ExtCtrls;

type
  myth = class(TThread)
    IdHTTP1: TIdHTTP;
    IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
    IdCookieManager1: TIdCookieManager;
    Button1: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Timer1: TTimer;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
    procedure meme;
  end;

implementation
uses Unit1;

procedure myth.Execute;
begin
  Synchronize(meme);
end;

procedure myth.meme;
var
  s:string; list, lista:TStringList;
  resul: string;
begin
  list:=TStringList.Create;
  Form1.Memo1.Clear;
  list.Add('...');
  list.Add('...');

  s:=IdHTTP1.Post('https://,list);
  list.Free;

  // (АВТОРИЗАЦИЯ)

  resul:=idHTTP1.Get('...');
  while Pos('tdn',resul) > 0 do begin // ЖМЕМ НА КНОПКИ
    lista:=TStringList.Create;
    lista.Add('...');
    IdHTTP1.Post('https:...,lista);
    lista.Free;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Comment: @Васька Пупкин - Всё тело потока заключено в Synchronize - а это значит, что поток блокирует главный поток на все время выполнения. В целом, это даже хуже, чем просто в главном потоке запустить.

Answer (score 1):

В классе потока вы объявили `IdHTTP1: TIdHTTP;` `IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;` `IdCookieManager1: TIdCookieManager;` которые нигде не создаются.

Также:

- Считается хорошей практикой объявлять классы с префиксом `Т`. Пример: `TIdHTTP`